# strength to women

Tags: women, mishlei

It says in [*Mishlei* 31:3](http://www.sefaria.org/Proverbs.31?lang=he-en&layout=heLeft&sidebarLang=all), *"Do not give your **strength** to women."*

What does this mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest reading is reminding noblemen how to behave.

> Don't spend all your energy womanizing!

Sure enough the next verse talks about ... drinking too much, another vice.